# Is there any difference between createQuery and using hibernate session interface?

Tags: hibernate

For example I have these line of code:

```
    session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    users = session.createQuery("from Users where id=?")
            .setParameter(0, id)
            .list();
```

And

```
    session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    users = session.get(Users.class, id);
```

I couldn't get clear which one is better and when should we use them?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case it returns instance of object Users (not list).

SO in the first case list of Users is expected.

If nothing is found the first case returns empty list but the second returns null. From Session.java

```
/**
 * Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier,
 * or null if there is no such persistent instance. (If the instance is already associated
 * with the session, return that instance. This method never returns an uninitialized instance.)
 *
 * @param clazz a persistent class
 * @param id an identifier
 *
 * @return a persistent instance or null
 */
public Object get(Class clazz, Serializable id);
```

Comment: So the only difference is what they return? Because I'm not sure about what exactly the program do when session.get(Users.class, id) is called.

Comment: You can set **show_sql=true** and see real SQL queries hibernate runs